# Magento : how to get a variable in config.xml

Tags: magento, controller, url-rewriting, admin, config

I overloaded the admin productController using rewrite in my module config.xml file:

```
<from><[CDATA [# ^ admin / catalog_product / #]]> </ from>
<to>/mymodule/catalog_produc/</to>
```

it works fine on the development environment, but it does not work in production, it can not find my controller.

After investigation I found that the admin path in local.xml is not the same on two environments:
production environment

```
<admin>
     <routers>
         <adminhtml>
             <args>
                 <frontName> <! [CDATA [admin-prod]]> </ frontName>
             </ args>
         </ adminhtml>
     </ routers>
</ admin>
```

development enviroment

```
<admin>
     <routers>
         <adminhtml>
             <args>
                 <frontName> <! [CDATA [*admin-prod*]]> </ frontName>
             </ args>
         </ adminhtml>
     </ routers>
</ admin>
```

My question is how to get the frontname dynamically in my module config.xml to set correctly and dynamically the rewrite like so:
<[CDATA [# ^ ***admin-prod*** / catalog_product / #]]> 
??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using an ancient Magento version (older than 1.3), you don't need this kind of regex based controller rewrites anymore. Use this instead:

**config.xml**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyNamespace_MyModule</mymodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Now Magento will look for `MyNamespace_MyModule_Catalog_ProductController` before `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` and use it instead if it was found, regardless of the route's front name.